# Showing that a subset of the real projective plane is a smooth manifold under given condition

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying to solve exercise 9.7 in Tu's introduction to manifolds:

> Let $F(x_{0},x_{1},x_{2})$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $k$.
>   Consider the homogeneous coordinates $[x_{0},x_{1},x_{2}]$ on the real
>   projective plane. The zero set $ Z(F)$ in $\mathbb{R}P^{2}$ is well defined.
>   Show that the hypersurface $Z(F)$ defined by $F(x_{0},x_{1},x_{2})=0$ is
>   smooth if $\partial F/\partial x_{0},\partial F/\partial x_{1},\partial F/\partial x_{2}$ are not simultaneously zero on $Z(F)$.

The exercise has a hint that defines $f([x_{0},x_{1},x_{2}])=F(1,x_{1}/x_{0},x_{2}/x_{0})$ on the open set $U_{0} =
\{[x_{0},x_{1},x_{2}]|x_0\neq 0\}$ and shows that $f$ and $F$ have the same
zero set in this open set.

What I'm trying to do: Define a smooth map from $U_{0}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ like
$\phi([x_{0},x_{1},x_{2}])=(x_{1}/x_{0},F(1,x_{1}/x_{0},x_{2}/x_{0})$ and take
advantage of the assumption that partial derivatives on $F$ don't vanish
together to show that the map $\phi$ is a local diffeomorphism via the inverse
function theorem. I'm unable to do the last step. I'm getting bogged down in
notation. If I show it, I can show that $Z(F)$ is defined by the points that
vanish on the last coordinate of $\phi$ and hence is a regular (embedded)
submanifold.

Any help making my answer work (or showing me another method) is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to show that the zero set of $F$ is smooth on each affine hyperplane $x_i=1$ in $R^3$ (by covering $RP^2$ via affine patches). I will do it for $i=3$. Then the zero set is given by the equation $F(x_1, x_2, 1)=0$. The assumption you have implies that $\nabla F$ does not vanish at each point of the set
$$
\{(x_1, x_2, 1): F(x_1, x_2, 1)=0\}
$$
Therefore, the intersection is a smooth curve. That's all.